# initialize and reassignment for string in c++ borland builder

Tags: string, initialization, c++builder, c++builder-6

I'm doing the following:

```
string strarr[]={"","",""};
if (a==b)
{
  strarr={"a","b","c"};
}
else
{
  strarr={"d","e","f"};
}
```

And I got expression syntax error on the line of reassignment to strarr.

Any ideas why?

And what can I do for initialize instead of:

```
string strarr[]={"","",""};
```

I'm using Borland C++Builder 6.

Comment: you can set the array at once just once (as declaration+definition of it)! if you need to have different init configurations you can use #define `#ifndef,#ifdef,#endif` pragmas but you can not use variable value as a condition. If you need to change the values of array during runtime you need to do it one by one ... If the strings are not changing then you can use pointer to different const arrays instead

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the curly brackets syntax is only used when initializing the array, for every C++ compilator. Thus you cannot use it for reassignment. You can use a loop or element-by-element assignment instead.

If the number of values that you want to assign is constant and their value is constant, you can put them in a constant array and iterate through it to fill your starr[] array.

Answer (score 0):

> I got expression syntax error on the line of reassignment to strarr
>
> Any ideas why?

You cannot reassign the array itself once it has been initialized.  You can only reassign its elements, eg:

```
string strarr[]={"","",""};
if (a==b)
{
  strarr[0] = "a";
  strarr[1] = "b";
  strarr[2] = "c";
}
else
{
  strarr[0] = "d";
  strarr[1] = "e";
  strarr[2] = "f";
}
```

> And what can I do for initialize instead of:
>
> string strarr[]={"","",""};

`std::string` has a default constructor that initializes it to an empty value, so there is no need to explicitly initialize it to `""` at all.  Remove the initial values, and specify the size of the array.  Let the compiler call the constructors for you:

```
string strarr[3];
```